# How to configure multiple subnets

Tags: linux, networking, routing, telnet, ifconfig

I have a scenario in which one computer needs to be a member of two subnets on the same physical network - 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24. I have achieved this using `ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.3.123/24 up` etc. The problem arises when I am trying to start a `telnet` session with another host, which is also a member of those two subnets. That host is accessible via telnet on both `IP` addresses, but when I try to connect to it, telnet hangs. This problem disappears when I remove either one of the two interfaces. I think it is also worth mentioning that there is no problem in `Windows`, with the same multiple `IP` setup. Since the host I am trying to connect to cannot be configured or modified, is it possible to solve this problem, say, by restricting 192.168.3.0 traffic only to eth0:1, or, perhaps having a different `MAC` address on that pseudo interface?

Comment: What distribution and version are you using?

Comment: Does telnet hang no matter which IP address you try to connect on?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a problem with the source IP address.  I imagine there are multiple ways to fix this.  Possibly the easiest would be to [disable reverse path filtering](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031).

An alternative option may be to rewrite packets to ensure the leaving address always matches the subnet with a couple of snat rules - possibly something like

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.x -o 192.168.3.123 --sport 25
-j SNAT --to 192.168.3.x
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aliased address is used **only** for telnetting into this server, then there is a very simple solution: tell `telnet` to bind to the specific address you want to use, as in:

```
  telnet -b 192.168.3.123   192.168.3.201
  telnet -b 192.168.2.123   192.168.2.201
```

having assumed that your pc has addresses 192.168.3.123/192.168.2.123 and the remote server has IP addresses 192.168.3.201/192.168.2.201. Notice that it is necessary for the source and destination addresses to belong to the same subnet, since you did not specify the existence of a network gateway.

If instead your use of the aliased address is more general (for instance, if you receive `telnet` calls, in which case you cannot specify the `-b` option as above), then you will need to learn about [policy routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/two-interfaces-two-addresses-two-gateways). But I guess we will cross that bridge when we get there.